# How to integrate $\int \frac{dx}{-x+te^{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

In the matlab I have tried

```
syms x;
fun=1/(x+2*exp(x));
int(fun,x)
```

but it won't give me desired answer, I want a solution of an indefinite integral. t is constant.

Comment: the functions in the title and qn body are not the same.

Comment: It cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions (or standard mathematical functions) even for $t=1$.

Comment: @cineel ... Take $t=-2$ in the title to get minus the integral in the body.  Thus, the OP claims Matlab cannot do the special case.  I confirm, neither can Maple.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac 1{t e^x -x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-x}}{t}\right)^{n+1}\,x^n$$
$$\int \frac {dx}{t e^x -x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  t^{-(n+1)}\int e^{-(n+1)x}\,x^n\,dx=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ \Gamma \big[n+1,(n+1) x\big]} {  \Big[(n+1) t\Big]^{(n+1)}} $$

In particular
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {dx}{t e^x -x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ \Gamma (n+1)} {  \Big[(n+1) t\Big]^{(n+1)}}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n$$
For large values of $n$
$$\frac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}=\frac{1}{ t} \left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^{(n+2)}=\frac{1}{e t}\Big[1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{19}{24 n^2} \Big]+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: clarify me one thing, let's assume this is a definate integral from limit (x: 0.2->1) then, would the solution be same? I think the matlab would give me answer in that case, am I correct?

Comment: @Vishwamitra. You have the antiderivative. The definite integral will be obtained using the bounds and will appear the incomplete gamma function. That's it.